# Querying Realm database to return dates

Tags: database, swift, nsdate, realm, predicates

I have a realm database and I'm trying to return dates. My query is as follows:

```
var jobsReturned = JobDates.objectsWhere("jobRestarted <= '\(testDate)' ")
```

The problem I'm getting is when I test I get an error that states, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'object must be of type date'

I have tested my two variables, jobRestarted and testDate to make sure both variables are dates. I use the following code:

```
println(" Test date is '\(_stdlib_getTypeName(testDate))' ")
```

and

```
println(" jobRestarted is '\(_stdlib_getTypeName(jobRestarted))' ")
```

Both lines of code confirm that both variables are NSDates. Why am I getting this error when both variables are dates?

Comment: Could you please share more of the code surrounding your usage of your `JobDates` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jobsReturned = JobDates.objectsWhere("jobRestarted <= %@", testDate)
```

Using string interpolation passes the string `"jobRestart <= '2015-01-27 21:48:03 +0000'"` to `objectsWhere`, which results in an `NSPredicate` comparing `jobRestart` to the string representation of the date, but what you need is an `NSPredicate` comparing `jobRestart` to an `NSDate`.